# spring cloud dataflow http post errors

Tags: spring-cloud-dataflow

trying the a demo on [getting-started](http://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-dataflow/docs/1.4.0.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#getting-started-deploying-streams-spring-cloud-dataflow) from Spring-Cloud DataFlow's website, I debugged the Spring-Cloud DataFlow local server 1.4.0.RELEASE in IDEA,  ran the SCDF shell with command line(windows),and i finished the steps as follows in shell:

1. app register --name http --type source --uri maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:http-source-rabbit:1.2.0.RELEASE
2. app register --name log --type sink --uri maven://org.springframework.cloud.stream.app:log-sink-rabbit:1.1.0.RELEASE
3. stream create --name httptest --definition "http --server.port=9000 | log" --deploy
4. http post --target http://localhost:9000 --data "hello world"

step **1-3** were fine, but when I ran the step 4, I kept getting error messages like:

> {"exception":"java.nio.charset.UnsupportedCharsetException",
>
> "path":"/",
>
> "error":"Internal Server Error",
>
> **"Message":"x-ibm1166",**
>
> "timestamp":1524899078020,
>
> "status":500
>
> }

Comment: What is your `chcp`? Can't you change it into the `437`? https://superuser.com/questions/482018/how-to-set-default-charset-in-windows-cmd

Comment: I changed it into 437 or 65001, didn't work, I tried the demo on OSX, it went fine, maybe it has something to do with OS.